# Intersection area of concentric ellipses

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, area

I need to find the area of intersection of two concentric ellipses. I imagine the concentricity should make this simpler than the general case, but the ellipses could be rotated.

Alternatively, if there is no simple solution to this. I could live with the area of parallelogram that is formed by the intersections points (when there are 4).

I don't have background in math or geometry, so any pointers is appreciated.
Intersecting ellipses:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the equations of the ellipses?

Comment: Yes, They are of the form found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate/434482#434482
Except `h`, and `k` are zero.

Comment: Probably easiest to do this in polar coordinates.

Comment: There's one special case asked [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598837/finding-the-area-between-the-two-ellipses-fracx2a2-fracy2b2-1-an) and we may have an oblique case as follows:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
  ax^2+bxy+cy^2<1 & \cap  & cx^2-bxy+ay^2<1 \\
  A &=& \dfrac{8}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}} \tan^{-1} \sqrt{\dfrac{a+c-\sqrt{(a-c)^2+b^2}}{a+c+\sqrt{(a-c)^2+b^2}}} \\
  a+c & > & 0
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

*This is a partial answer.*

I would say the hardest part is likely finding the points of intersection. In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/425412/35416) I discuss the generic approach, which involves solving a quadratic equation of at least degree $3$. However, since your ellipses are both centered around the origin, a quadratic equation will suffice.

Rewrite your ellipses in the following form (by expanding the numerator of the form you say you have):

$$a_1x^2+b_1y^2+c_1xy=d_1\qquad a_2x^2+b_2y^2+c_2cy=d_2$$

Then you can combine them: take $d_2$ times the first equation minus $d_1$ times the second and you get

$$(a_1d_2-a_2d_1)x^2+(b_1d_2-b_2d_1)y^2+(c_1d_2-c_2d_1)xy=0$$

This is the equation of a pair of lines passing through the origin and through the points of intersection. Next compute

$$t = \sqrt{(c_1d_2-c_2d_1)^2-4(a_1d_2-a_2d_1)(b_1d_2-b_2d_1)}$$

The lines are now described by one of these equations:

\begin{align*}
2(a_1d_2-a_2d_1)x + (c_1d_2-c_2d_1\pm t)y &= 0 \\
(c_1d_2-c_2d_1\pm t)x + 2(b_1d_2-b_2d_1)y &= 0
\end{align*}

Generally just picking one of these two equations is enough, since with the $\pm$ in it it will already give you both the lines. If you are unlucky, though, and one of the lines coincides with one of the coordinate axes, then either $(a_1d_2-a_2d_1)$ or $(b_1d_2-b_2d_1)$ will be zero. Using the equation with the zero there will cause one of the equations to become $0x+0y=0$ for one of the cases of the $\pm$. In those cases better use the equation where there is no zero.

Now you have the equation of a line, and you can intersect that with the ellipse. And then you have the points of intersection, and can use these for angle computation. I will not include all details for that in my answer, but I invite other answers to cover these parts.